# BootStrap Carousel Not cycling through images

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am having a problem with my carousel that when it reaches the last image it just shows nothing and does not recycle through images over and over again like I want it too.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide hidden-sm" data-ride="carousel">

<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>


</ol>

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->

<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

    <div class="item active"><img src="images/carousel/seattle_skyline.jpg" alt="skyline"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="images/carousel/jewelry_workshop.jpg" alt="jewelry"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="images/carousel/pottery_workshop.jpg" alt="pottery"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="images/carousel/paining_workshop.jpg" alt="painting"</div>
    <div class="item"><img src="images/carousel/quickskecth_workshop.jpg" alt="sketch"></div>
</div>

<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

Comment: You would have to add a jquery function to it i guess, is this all the code? can you wrap it into a jsfiddle?